# Pyevolve with Anaconda

Tags: installation, pyevolve

I am using the Anaconda python distribution for 64 bit, windows

https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

I am now trying to do some genetic search, and tried to install Pyevolve

http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/

Unfortunately it crapped out saying

```
"Python 2.6 not found in registry"
```

I do have Python 2.7.6 through Anaconda. Any way around the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed it using binstar:

1. Look for available packages: `binstar search -t conda pyevolve` (two packages found OpenMDAO/pyevolve and greole/pyevolve)
2. Ask for details of chosen package: `binstar show openmdao/pyevolve` (install link given)
3. Install package: `conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/OpenMDAO pyevolve`
4. Enjoy working with pyevolve!

My system: Win8, 64-bit, Python 2.7.8, Anaconda 2.1.0 (32-bit).

Comment: a shorter version: conda install -c openmdao pyevolve=0.6

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda suggests using "conda" for package management. There are some package not available in its repository. You can try command below:

```
conda search Pyevolve
```

Pyevolve seems depend on Python 2.6, you can try conda to setup a new environment in 2.6 version.